# How to get distinct records but on base on first 2 digits only in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get distinct records (only one field) from a MySQL table, and that field contain only digits.

Example:

```
00010000
01111100
01112000
01118000
02301201
```

But distinct records is considered on base on first 2 digits. So in the case above, I need to get back only 3 records:

```
00010000
01112000
02301201
```

More over, I would like to trim the rest of the digits, so the actual end result should be:

```
00
01 
02
```

So distinct and group by will not cut here. Any idea?

Comment: What is the logic by which `01112000` gets chosen from `(01111100, 01112000, 01118000)` ?

Comment: Simply it is first record that starts with 01

Comment: No, it's the _second_ record starting with `01`, but maybe your requirement is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the trimmed value, try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(yourColumn,1,2) as trimmedval
FROM Table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(yourColumn,1,2)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3

Comment: I just tried it, works for me. Is your column a text field ?

Comment: Field is varchar

Comment: Then it should work, can you copy it again? I’ve edited it in the beginning , maybe you copied before.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted the least value from among duplicates, you could try:

```
SELECT t1.col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LEFT(col, 2) AS prefix, MIN(col) AS min_col
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY LEFT(col, 2)
) t2
    ON LEFT(t1.col, 2) = t2.prefix AND
       t1.col = t2.min_col;
```

Note: Numbers in MySQL don't start with zeroes, so your requirement (and this answer) only make sense if your column is text.

Comment: Yes, it is a varchar

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` will work fine with `LEFT` to give the results you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(value, 2)) AS value
FROM data
ORDER BY value
```

Output

```
00
01
02
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vAEsJHs6wtTbxHGPvgYXgq/0)

Comment: I see this answer too late. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2417624 yes - I noticed once I posted it you had already accepted another answer. That's ok, I hope this was useful anyway.